# How to retrieve a lost connection in php?

Tags: php, header, connection

[`connection_aborted()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) tells us if the connection with client is lost.

Is there any function that tells if the connection is retrieved?

Once the connection is retrieved I need to send the error in the header()

Answer (score 0):

You can know the status of the connection status using the function  [connection_status](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php)